# How do I configure HornetQ for STOMP in Immutant 2

Tags: clojure, websocket, hornetq, stomp, immutant

My ultimate purpose is to make WebSocket clients participate in messaging. This seems to be supported and well documented in the sibling project [TorqueBox](http://torquebox.org/documentation/3.1.2/stomp.html) but I can't find any information in the Immutant docs.

Comment: Do you actually require STOMP? If not, proxying messages to and from a WebSocket client should be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, I guess proxying could also do. And I must admit this sounds like a much more attractive option after reading how one would need to open a separate port for the websocket communication  and let users authenticate with passwords stored in plaintext xml...